# To stop Excel updating calling Excel from AutoHotkey via COM

Tags: excel, com, autohotkey, vba

Let an handle to our currently active Excel sheet is created in an `.ahk` script through

```
Xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
```

and then some values are managed, as instance through

```
Xl.Sheets("Book1").Range("K2:K239").Copy
```

It looks like AutoHotkey allows for using VBA syntax to interact with Excel workbooks and sheets, but what if I wanted to stop the Excel autoupdating function like I would do in VBA?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

I've tried something like

```
Xl.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and

```
Xl.ScreenUpdating = False
```

but AutoHotkey returns error in both the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you are missing is a colon... `Xl.ScreenUpdating := False`